# DAU and MAU on the same table: aka how to count distinct over moving 30 days windows

Tags: sql, netezza

I need to calculate DAU (daily active users) and MAU (monthly active users) from a table like the following:

```
| customer_id | date | purchase amount |
```

My  ideal result will be having a table like this:

```
| date | DAU | MAU |
```

where DAU = count (distinct customer_id) in the day corresponding to the column `| date |`
MAU = count (distinct customer_id) from the period ranging from the day corresponding to the column `| date |` and going  back to 30 days.

I can envision it may be done using sub-queries, but I'm using Netezza an it does not allow me to use them.

Any thoughts how to do the moving count distinct (like a 30 days moving average)?
thanks a lot

Comment: You should add the Netezza tag to your question, so people who know what that is might come read it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll add it right now